# jdbc using sqlnet.ora

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a program that wants to make a connection to an oracle database on our network. This program is written in java and has to use jdbc. Our PC's are setup to use sqlnet.ora files to determine the order of how to resolve. All our PC's first check ldap (which the ldap file is on all these PC's pointing to the ldap server) and then secondly to use tnsnames.ora file, but this file is empty now so basically I want to use ldap, but do it via sqlnet.ora. Any ideas what the connection would look like for the url parameter?

Comment: Are you using the Type 4 (thin) JDBC driver?  Or the Type 2 (OCI) JDBC driver?  If you want to use the Oracle client's network configuration files, you would need to be using the OCI driver.

Comment: Never done this before so not sure. We have Oracle client 11x installed on all the users PC's so thinking the OCI driver comes with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#05_04)

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@<<TNS alias>>
```

where `<<TNS alias>>` is the LDAP entry that you would use if you were connecting via, say, SQL*Plus

Answer (score 3):

From the [JDBC Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIDIJCE)

> *The oracle.net.tns_admin system property must be set to the location of the tnsnames.ora file so that the JDBC Thin driver can locate the tnsnames.ora file. For example:*

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "c:\\Temp");
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@tns_entry";
DriverManager.getConnection(url, ...);
```

Because of the system property, the thin driver is able to locate the tnsnames.ora file and thus can resolve the TNS name specified in the URL. Because the thin driver is usually intended to work *without* an Oracle client installation, this is not enabled by default.

As far as I remember, you *only* need tnsnames.ora, you don't need an Oracle client when using the thin driver even when specifying a TNS name.

If your program does not allow setting system properties you have two options:

1. Specify it when starting your program `java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=c:/foobar ...`
2. Set an environment variable `JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS` that contains `-Doracle.net.tns_admin=c:/foobar`. That will then be picked up by *any* Java program automtically

Comment: Can't use TNS names. The TNS names file is empty on these PC's. Need to use sqlnet.ora which has in it to first look at ldap file. Also this is connecting via a login type screen for the app not code, so no where to add the property.

Comment: There is no where to set this property via this program's connection configuration screen.

Comment: @user441521: do you have an Oracle client installed on those machines (instantclient or regular one?) In that case you could use the OCI driver see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/instclnt.htm#autoId16

Comment: @user441521: you can provide the parameter in several ways. See my edit